# @NotEmpty annotation in Spring Boot with IBM WebSphere not working

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, websphere, bean-validation

I have a problem with @NotEmpty (or @NotBlank) annotation in spring boot with IBM WebSphere 9.0.5.15

I have this DTO

```java
    ...
    @NotEmpty(message = "name must not be empty")
    private String name;
    ...
```

When I run this code locally on Apache Tomcat, everything is fine and annotation works, so name can not be null neither empty string

But when I upload the war file on IBM WebSphere the annotation seems not to work. I can pass either null or empty string for name, and there is no Exception

I looked across internet to find if IBM WebSphere has some issue with this and can not find anything,
So is there any solution for this?

**NOTE:** When using annotation `@NotNull` everything is fine even on WebSphere, but I need the "name" to not be empty also.

Controller:

```java
    @PostMapping("/enter-user")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public User createUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserInput user) {
        return userService.createUser(user);
    }
```

Service:

```java
    @Transactional
    public User createLiceSoLicniPodatoci(User user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
```

Comment: Feels like you are using the validation provider available on WebSphere instead of the one shipped with your war. Make sure you have properly set the classloading in IBM websphere (PARENT_LAST or something like that), to make your application classes be preferred over the websphere ones.

Comment: I found only this options in WebSphere that looks like what you said, but still it does not work---
Class loader order :
1) Classes loaded with parent class loader first (this is checked by default)
 2) Classes loaded with local class loader first (parent last)  (I checked this)

Comment: Then I'm out of options, did you inlude the actual dependencies? Which Spring Boot version? what does your configuration look like? Show your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere supports the core JSR-303 validations, which, as you can see, apparently dos not include `@NotEmpty`.

See the supported list at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/9.0.5?topic=api-bean-validation-built-in-constraints

From that list, I think you can accomplish what you want with a combination of `@NotNull` and like `@Size` or `@Pattern`. We do this in some of our validations. e.g.

```java
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1,max=30,message="Application ID must be between 1 and 30 characters")
    private String applicationId;
```

Or, as M.Denium suggested above, look into preempting the WebSphere implementation with another that you'd have to provide with your app. I'm not sure changing the classloader policy would be sufficient by itself, but I'm not sure it wouldn't. Just noting that changing the classloader policy is usually a last resort.

([This blog post](https://dougbreaux.github.io/2018/05/23/springmvc-jsr303-websphere.html) where I explore JSR-303 validation with WebSphere and Spring might also be helpful.)